# seeing memory_used_index_bytes having 4G while there are no index

Tags: aerospike

Aerospike version: Community Edition - 4.0.11

We have lot of data in our aerospike setup, but there are no indexes setup. `aql` command `show indexes` does not shows anything, but when I run `asinfo "namespace/my_namespace"` I see lot of bytes in field: `memory_used_index_bytes`, which as par [docs](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#memory_used_index_bytes) is:

> Amount of memory occupied by the index for this namespace. For server version 4.3 and above, if your index is not stored in DRAM (persisted), see index_flash_used_bytes. For index-type set to flash (persisted index), the value will be 0.

What does this memory actually contains, is it index used for primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, this is the memory used for the primary index, 64 bytes per record. Refer to this page as well: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity/.